# What does ?cat=2-5-results mean at the end of URLs?

Tags: taxonomy

I'm seeing a lot of visits in my Analytics to my home page with the query string "?cat=2-5-results". These pages are getting a lot of traffic. To the best of my knowledge, I'm not using this parameter on my site anywhere. If I google "wordpress ?cat=2-5-results" I find a lot of other sites with the same phantom pages.

Anyone know what this means?

My site: http://www.barbadospropertylist.com

Here are how the pages appear in GA:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used (together with the search query) to measure number of results for a search query, it's not supposed to show up in Analytics like this, this could only happen due to people scraping your site and clicking through to the actual URL...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how exactly it is used, but I have an idea where it comes from.

This exact string is used in [Google Analytics for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) plugin ([source](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/google-analytics-for-wordpress/tags/4.0.9/googleanalytics.php#L872)).

Comment: I'll ask Yoast then...